# Update Session variable on last call of RowDataBound

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm working on a `Web Forms` project. It's an old one with lot of abstractions added for this time. On one of my pages I have a gridview with pagination. I'm trying to extend the current implementation with a check if something have been changed on the current gridview page when the user is going to the next one. I think I managed to do this by using two session variables. My problem is with one of them which is populated on the `RowDataBound` event, and since there is some abstraction above the original `ASP.NET` session my code inside the `RowDataBound` event looks like this:

```
 SessionWrapper.GetInstance().RemoveSessionItem("OriginalData");
 SessionWrapper.GetInstance().SetSessionItem("OriginalData", someData);
```

This is called at the very end of the `RowDataBound` implementation and for example in my case the gridview shows 10 records per page so I remove the key 10 times and right after that I add it with the updated data where `someData` is a collection to each record is appended on each call of `RowDataBound`.

What I would like to do is finding a way which is the last execution of `RowDataBound` and do the above step only once. Since I know that there are 10 pages per page I could imeplement a counter and check against it, but then what about if on the last page I have less than 10 records, or the total records are less then 10?

So is there way to reliably check when is the last call of a `RowDataBound`?

Comment: Have you tried the `DataBound` event?  That may fire after the last `RowDataBound` even is called.

Comment: @Tim No. I thought that there might be a suitable event after the `RowDataBound` but I didn't know which one I could use, so yeah this I think is a possible solution, thanks for which. Other than that do you think it's possible to use the `RowDataBound`?

Comment: The only other way I can think of off the top of my head would be to keep track of the number of times RowDataBound is called via a class level variable and execute the Session items on the last one, but that strikes me as a serious kludge and pretty brittle as well.  I'd try DataBound first and test it to see if it does indeed fire after all the RowDataBound events.

Comment: @Tim I agree with you. I really like the `DataBound` solution. If you want, post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using `DataBound` to do the updating of `Session`.  Something like this:

```
protected void GridView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SessionWrapper.GetInstance().RemoveSessionItem("OriginalData");
    SessionWrapper.GetInstance().SetSessionItem("OriginalData", someData);
}
```

This assumes that `someData` is accessible at the scope of this method.  If it's not, you'll need to store it in a class level variable or in the Session.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `RowDataBound` Footer row, then you will know how many rows there are.

```
int counter = 0;

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        counter = 0;
    }
    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        counter++;
    }
    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        Label1.Text = counter + " rows in GridView";
    }
}
```

Comment: What if there is no footer? This will break.

Comment: "If you use RowDataBound Footer row" would seem to make it clear that if you're not using it, this solution won't work.....

Comment: I thought so too so at first I tested with `ShowFooter="true"` and then hide it with `e.Row.Visible = false;` in the `DataControlRowType.Footer` of the `RowDataBound`, but with some testing it seems it is always executed, with or without a footer in the grid.